# Time flow analysis and theoretical flow time

Tags: economics

I'm working for my program for economy where I have an example I try to solve.

[image: flow]

The flow rate is 0.15 units/min and

- A - 1 server: flow time = 5, capacity = 0.2
- B - 2 servers: flow time = 9, capacity = 0.22
- C - 1 server: flow time = 6, capacity  0.17

I have to find the Theoretical flow time. If I follow Little law, I have to calculate current inventory for each server.

- A = 0.75 units
- B = 1.35 units
- C = 0.90 units

So the next step is to calculate how much time is used for processing in each server.

- A: we have 0.75 units and capacity is 0.2 so 0.75/0.2 = 3.75 minutes
- B: as we have 2 servers here, it means that capacity * 2, so 3.06 minutes
- C: 5.29 minutes

The theory is that theoretical flow time is the maximum, so A + B = 6.81 minutes. Is this correct?